# Get Printer Status from Java PrintService

Tags: java, java-print

How can I get Printer status from a network printer that has driver installed on out PC? In particular I want to know if the printer is busy (currently printing) or idle (just waiting for print jobs)?

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [PrintService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/PrintService.html):

```
PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
```

Comment: I know PrintService class. I just want to know what I am asking is even possible